# Notation: which notes in this piano sheet are flat?

Tags: sheet-music, accidentals

In the attached music sheet there seems to be 4 flat notes which means all but one notes are flat, but which note isn't flat?

Seems to me that it is G, but I see that it has the natural sign at some places, which means that it should be flat by default.

[image: sheet music - stevie wonder - free]

Comment: The maximum number of flats (without getting into double flats) is SEVEN.

Comment: Don't be under the misapprehension that all flats are the black keys on a piano. True, they're the first 5 to be called flats in a key signature, but C flat and F flat are, actual flats in some keys.

Comment: Can you work from a more accurate score?  This has several obvious errors.

Comment: @aparente001 actually, one can have even more than 7, but some of them will happen to be double. Up to 11 could be reasonably used.

Comment: @fraxinus - did you see the parentheses in my comment?  "without getting into double flats"

Comment: @fraxinus "Reasonably used"? Any composer who uses more than 6 accidentals is a sadist who enjoys watching performers suffer. Any key outside of 6 accidentals is the enharmonic equivalent of a key within 6 accidentals, the only difference being that one is harder to read. Fb major, with 6 flats and a double flat, could just as easily be written as the much easier key of E major.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the key signature specifies flats on B, E, A and D, so you get Bb, Eb, Ab, Db. Still you might see unnecessary accidentals such as a natural on the G. This can be the case if a previous measure had the same note but with an alteration (i.e. suppose the previous measure had a Gb), or if the harmony in that particular part of the piece strongly implies an alteration such as Gb, so you are reminded of the actual accidental. These accidentals are called *cautionary accidentals* or *courtesy accidentals*.

Basically the editor may put in as many redundant accidentals as he wants, and should use this to make the score easier to read.

In this particular case (I can only spot the naturals in mm. 10 and 26) the naturals seem to be quite unmotivated to me, and I suppose they are engraving issues. There are more problems with the score, such as m. 16 having **4** B naturals right next to each other, as well as collision between lyrics and notes.

So this does not appear to be an edition of professional quality, which results in some weird stuff. From the use of Lilypond’s notation font and the FreeSerif font I presume this is done using an older version of MuseScore. I presume the person who did this score used the accidental buttons in MuseScore to change the alteration, which will also force the print of the accidental.

Comment: “redundant accidentals[…] to make the score easier to read.” — IMHO, cautionary accidentals only make the score easier to read if they're clearly _indicated_ to be cautionary (i.e. in brackets). Otherwise, if they're indistinguishable from ‘proper’ accidentals, they make the score _harder_ to read, wasting time and brainpower checking whether you missed a previous accidental or key signature (or clef) change, or trying to second-guess the editor… For my benefit, if nothing else, _please_ put cautionary accidentals in brackets!

Comment: @gidds Yes. Cautionary accidentals mess with my head more than the barline accidental breaks do, especially in piano music when there are often more than one at a time.

Comment: @gidds I’d disagree. Using brackets or parentheses on accidentals will mess up spacing, and may be confused with accidental suggestions. It is the editor’s choice whether to place cautionary accidentals at all, and optimally he will do so in sensible places, that is places where such a reminder is in fact of use.

Comment: @Lazy In my experience, spacing is a non-issue. (Lilypond handles it very neatly, for example; I can't recall any significant layout changes resulting from enabling cautionaries.) And if necessary, editorial suggestions can be distinguished by using square brackets (as for other editorial annotations), unlike the round ones used for cautionaries. (Some editors place suggested accidentals over/under the note instead of before it — I find that awkward to read, but it's another way to distinguish.)

Answer (score 4):

The G naturals are unnecessary, as are, for example, the multiple natural signs in measure 12. This is just a poorly notated arrangement.

Comment: and what about those quadruplets?

Comment: Whoa, there are even G-s without natural signs...

Answer (score 4):

You're correct that G is natural. It is in Ab major, so B, E, A, and D are flat. The naturals are just due to the sloppiness of the score. The score's sloppiness is apparent in other aspects. Unnecessary quadruplets, doubled 8th rests when a quarter rest works fine. The notes cut off the lyrics as well. It's just an overall poorly notated, messy score.

Comment: And 4 different keys noted at the top in butchered solfege-ese...  I'm guessing there's key-changes later in the song maybe?  But normally only the first key is notated at the top.  And I've never seen anyone use "Lab" or "Solb" to imply the flat of those keys, even when they do insist on solfege key naming.  (Also using 'b' to mean '♭' just adds confusion...)